# Does GDAL has any substitute function for the ExtractByMask in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, gdal

I am now using arcpy: arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(weight_raster,elev)
both weight_raster and elev are raster data in different size.

I want to use functions in GDAL to replace this arcpy methods. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GDAL_Calc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) will perform this operation:

```
gdal_calc.py -A weight_raster -B elev --outfile=result.tif --calc="B*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=0
```

This multiplies B (elev) by A > 0 which is 0 for less than or equal to and 1 for greater than (boolean 0=False, 1=True) so the raster will be 0 where B fails the test and A where B passes the test. Note that this will cause problems where 0 is inside the valid range as any 0 values from the input will now be nodata, you can filter these by performing a preliminary calc on elev:

```
gdal_calc.py -A elev --outfile=elev_offset.tif --calc="A+0.00001*(A==0)"
```

Which adds (offsets) 0.00001 to cells that are true 0 to make them not 0 any more, this shouldn't affect the raster too much as it's 1/10th of a milimetre.

Normally extract operations are done with a binary raster, which can be created with [GDAL_Rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) from a shapefile or other OGR format.

Another limitation of GDAL_Calc is that the rasters must be the same size and origin, you can clip them to the same extent using [GDAL_Translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with the `-projwin` (in dataset coordinates) or `-srcwin` options (in cells).